# internal service error when doing live payment (fine on sandbox)

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to make a live direct payment via rest api (using paypal-rest-sdk on node.js) for 1 dollar by using amex credit card and I get internal service error message. Everything works fine on sandbox.  I don't get any more details on the error.

Debug id is cb942d235c44b

What may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to process the **"AMEX" card transactions which is not enabled on your account .** You can try to process the payment using visa , mastercard etc and it will work fine. To enable the AMEX transactions on your account you can contact our business support line on the below details :

**Please contact our toll free Merchant Solutions line at 888-215-5506.  Agents are available from 6:00 AM CST to 11:00 PM CST Monday through Friday, and 8:00 AM to 10:00 PM CST Saturday and Sunday.**

Comment: Where, on my paypal profile, can I see the list of credit cards that are enabled for my account?

Comment: These information is not mentioned in the PayPal account . Generally all the cards are accepted by default for US merchants ie.Visa,MC,Disc,AMEX.**Note** For direct payment only, American Express restricts direct card acceptance merchants in certain business categories. Merchants are required to accept the American Express Card Acceptance agreement in order to process American Express cards directly. You can refer below link for more info :[link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/#regionaldifferences)